# jqgrid row id and gridrow id

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

Ive made a few posts regarding jqgrid now and am getting the slowly but surely.

I have code that generates buttons for each row when the grid is generated in the complete grid function:

```
gridComplete: function(){ 
                var ids = jQuery("#rowed2").jqGrid('getDataIDs'); 
                for(var i=0;i < ids.length;i++){ 
                    var cl = ids[i]; 
                    be = "<input style='height:22px;width:20px;' type='button' value='E' alt='Edit Location' onclick=\"jQuery('#rowed2').editGridRow('"+cl+"');\" />"; 
                    se = "<input style='height:22px;width:20px;' type='button' value='S' onclick=\"jQuery('#rowed2').saveRow('"+cl+"');\" />"; 
                    ce = "<input style='height:22px;width:20px;' type='button' value='C' onclick=\"jQuery('#rowed2').restoreRow('"+cl+"');\" />";
                    fl = "<input style='height:22px;width:50px;' type='button' value='Find' alt='Find Location' class='findMe' rel='"+cl+"' />";
                    gc = "<input style='height:22px;width:50px;' type='button' value='Geo' class='geocodeMe' rel='"+cl+"' />";
                    jQuery("#rowed2").jqGrid('setRowData',ids[i],{Actions:fl+gc}); 
                } 
            }
```

for my edit delete functions it was posting the jqgrid row id as the id parameter, which needed to be the recordset id so i could filter what record to edit/delete.
so i set the id_~mdt colulm to key:true so it passed this as the id.

now i cant retrive the grid row id using: (it was returning the gridrow ref before, now it returns the recordId)

```
ids = jQuery("#rowed2").jqGrid('getDataIDs');
```

SO how do i retrive the gridrowId now??? to put in the rel attribute of my button

I am assuming i should be using something other than `getRowIds` like get `GridRowID` or something but cant find in the wiki what to use...

```
gridComplete: function(){ 
                var ids = jQuery("#rowed2").jqGrid('getDataIDs'); 
                for(var i=0;i < ids.length;i++){ 
                    var cl = ids[i]; 
                    be = "<input style='height:22px;width:20px;' type='button' value='E' alt='Edit Location' onclick=\"jQuery('#rowed2').editGridRow('"+cl+"');\" />"; 
                    se = "<input style='height:22px;width:20px;' type='button' value='S' onclick=\"jQuery('#rowed2').saveRow('"+cl+"');\" />"; 
                    ce = "<input style='height:22px;width:20px;' type='button' value='C' onclick=\"jQuery('#rowed2').restoreRow('"+cl+"');\" />";
                    fl = "<input style='height:22px;width:50px;' type='button' value='Find' alt='Find Location' class='findMe' rel='"+cl+"' />";
                    gc = "<input style='height:22px;width:50px;' type='button' value='Geo' class='geocodeMe' rel='"+cl+"' />";
                    jQuery("#rowed2").jqGrid('setRowData',ids[i],{Actions:fl+gc}); 
                } 
            }
        });
```

heres my full code with col set-up :

```
myGrid = jQuery("#rowed2").jqGrid({ 
        url:'data/stokistdata_s_json.php?q=3', 
        datatype: "json",
        mtype: "POST", 
        rowNum:10, 
        rowList:[50,100,150,200,300,400,500,600], 
        pager: '#prowed2', 
        sortname: 'name_mdt', 
        viewrecords: true, 
        gridview:true,
        sortorder: "asc", 
        rowNum:50, 
        scroll: true, 
        editurl: "data/server.php", 
        caption:"Stockist's and Orchid days",
        colNames:[
            'Actions',
            'id',
            'Type', 
            'Name', 
            'Geo Address',
            'Display Address',
            'Telephone',
            'Email', 
            'website', 
            'lat', 
            'lng', 
            'flag', 
            'description', 
            'active'
        ], 
        colModel:[{
            name:'Actions',
            index:'Actions',
            width:100,
            sortable:false,
            search:false
        }, {
            name:'id_mdt',
            index:'id_mdt',
            width:15,
            align:"left",
            sortable:true,
            search:false,
            hidden: true, 
            editable: true, 
            editrules: { edithidden: true }, 
            editoptions:{readonly:true},
            hidedlg: true,
            key: true
        }, {
            name:'id_etp',
            index:'id_etp', 
            width:90, 
            align:"left",
            sortable:true,
            editable:true,
            edittype:"select",
            formatter:'select',
            editoptions:{value:{1:'Stokist',0:'Orchid Day'}},
            editrules:{required:true},
            search:true,
            stype:'select',
            sopt: ['eq'],
            searchoptions:{value:{'':'All',1:'Stockist',2:'Orchid Day'}}
        },{
            name:'Name_mdt',
            index:'Name_mdt',
            align:"left", 
            width:150,
            editable:true,
            editrules:{required:true},
            search:true,
            stype:'text',
            sopt:['cn']
        }, {
            name:'geoaddr_mdt',
            index:'geoaddr_mdt',
            width:150, 
            align:"left",
            editable:true,
            search:false,
            edittype:"textarea", 
            editoptions:{rows:"3",cols:"30"}
        }, {
            name:'displayaddr_mdt',
            index:'displayaddr_mdt', 
            width:150, 
            align:"left",
            editable:true,
            search:false,
            edittype:"textarea", 
            editoptions:{rows:"3",cols:"30"}
        }, {
            name:'telephone_mdt',
            index:'telephone_mdt', 
            width:80,
            align:"left",
            editable:true,
            search:false
        }, {
            name:'email_mdt',
            index:'email_mdt', 
            editrules:{email:true, required:false},
            width:80, 
            align:"left",
            sortable:false,
            editable:true,
            search:false
        }, {
            name:'website_mdt',
            index:'website_mdt', 
            editrules:{url:true, required:false},
            width:80, 
            align:"left",
            sortable:false,
            editable:true,
            search:false
        }, {
            name:'lat_mdt',
            index:'lat_mdt', 
            width:40, 
            align:"left",
            sortable:false,
            editable:true,
            search:false
        } , {
            name:'lng_mdt',
            index:'lng_mdt', 
            width:40, 
            align:"left",
            sortable:false,
            editable:true,
            search:false
        }, {
            name:'flag_mdt',
            index:'flag_mdt', 
            width:20, 
            align:"left",
            sortable:true,
            editable:true,
            edittype:"select",
            editoptions: {value:{1:'Flagged',0:'No Flag'}},
            search:true,//
            stype:'select',
            searchoptions:{value:{'':'All',1:'Flagged',0:'No Flag'}}//{value:":Both;1:Flagged;0:No Flag"}
        }, {
            name:'description_mdt',
            index:'description_mdt', 
            width:150, 
            align:"left",
            sortable:false,
            editable:true,
            search:false,
            edittype:"textarea", 
            editoptions:{rows:"3",cols:"30"}
        }, {
            name:'active_mdt',
            index:'active_mdt', 
            width:20, 
            align:"left",
            sortable:true,
            editable:true,
            edittype:"select",
            editoptions: {value:{1:'Active',0:'Hidden'}},
            search:true,//
            stype:'select',
            searchoptions:{value:{'':'All','1':'Active','0':'Hidden'}} //{value:":Both;1:Active;0:Hidden"}
        }], search : {
             caption: "Search...",
             Find: "Find",
             Reset: "Reset",
             matchText: " match",
             rulesText: " rules"
       },

        gridComplete: function(){ 
            var ids = jQuery("#rowed2").jqGrid('getDataIDs'); 
            for(var i=0;i < ids.length;i++){ 
                var cl = ids[i]; 
                be = "<input style='height:22px;width:20px;' type='button' value='E' alt='Edit Location' onclick=\"jQuery('#rowed2').editGridRow('"+cl+"');\" />"; 
                se = "<input style='height:22px;width:20px;' type='button' value='S' onclick=\"jQuery('#rowed2').saveRow('"+cl+"');\" />"; 
                ce = "<input style='height:22px;width:20px;' type='button' value='C' onclick=\"jQuery('#rowed2').restoreRow('"+cl+"');\" />";
                fl = "<input style='height:22px;width:50px;' type='button' value='Find' alt='Find Location' class='findMe' rel='"+cl+"' />";
                gc = "<input style='height:22px;width:50px;' type='button' value='Geo' class='geocodeMe' rel='"+cl+"' />";
                jQuery("#rowed2").jqGrid('setRowData',ids[i],{Actions:fl+gc}); 
            } 
        }
    }); 

    jQuery("#rowed2").jqGrid('navGrid',"#prowed2",
        {edit:true,add:true,del:true,search:true,refresh:true},
        {closeOnEscape:true, recreateForm: true, width:500},
        {closeOnEscape:true, recreateForm: true, width:500}    // Add options

    ); 
    myGrid.jqGrid('filterToolbar',{defaultSearch:'cn',stringResult:true});
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know if I understand completely your question.

Usually your row id should be your record id unless you're specifying a different one when you pass your JSON data.
The best option is to pass to the jqGrid your record id so you can refer to your database row if you have to do some CRUD operation.

If you want to fetch some other fields you can use:

```
var ret = myGrid.jqGrid('getRowData', id);
```

Now you can access the colums of your grid: ret[0]

Comment: hmm, i ahve the id_mdt col set as the key, without this i do not recive the row id of the record in the db, which is needed for the edit/delete functions, it seems though that now i have set this the id before i was getting an id of (jqg_899) or something similar, now i dont recive the row id from the grid jsut the record id, i hope that makes sense if so i will update the question

Comment: remember that the jqgrid rowid must be unique otherwise it messes up cause it tries to create the same id for a TR. You can simply pass as many IDs or fiels as you want. If you do not want to show the column simply hide it -> hidden:true

Comment: thanks for the clarification, i hadnt realised that the grid row id would take the same as the primary key id of my recordset, thinking about it, it makes a lot of sense!!!

Comment: @Dizzy Bryan High: No problem.Each one of us has made this mistake at first ... but, as you said, it makes sense.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old post, but I had a similar issue where I wasn't able to get the accepted post code to work.

The jqGrid has various rows so I gave my buttons the same class name and got the closest tr, id attribute in the click function for the button and it's working well for me.

```
    $('.buttonClassName').click(function (){
        var row = $(this).closest("tr").attr("id")
        alert(row);
    });
```